# How do I set up my AsyncTask method if my images are being displayed in another class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have my method I'm calling the AsyncTask method from:

```
public static Drawable[] queryAppIcon() throws ParseException, IOException {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("AndroidStoreContent");
    query.whereExists("appIcon");
    List<ParseObject> ParseResult = query.find();
    // initialize Drawable array
    final Drawable[] appIconDrawable = new Drawable[ParseResult.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < ParseResult.size(); i++) {
        ParseFile pf = (ParseFile) ParseResult.get(i).get("appIcon");
        appIconDrawable[i] = DownloadImageTask.execute(pf);
    }
    return appIconDrawable;
}
```

the AsyncTask:

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<ParseFile, Void, Drawable> {

    ParseFile pf = null;

    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(ParseFile... pf) {
        this.pf = pf[0]; 
        fetchDrawable(pf);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        // do I do anything here?
    }

    public Drawable fetchDrawable(ParseFile pf) {
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = (InputStream) new URL(pf.getUrl()).getContent();
            return Drawable.createFromStream(is,null);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I know I'm supposed to have an onPostExecute, but the thing is the array of Drawable is going into another class for the ViewActivity:

```
    // Get application image from Parse
    Drawable[] appIconUrl = new Drawable[0];
    try {
        appIconUrl = ParseContent.queryAppIcon();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < appText.length; i++) {
        OtherRowItem item = new OtherRowItem(appIconUrl[i], appText[i]);
        otherRowItems.add(item);
    }

    otherSize = otherRowItems.size();
    otherListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.other_games_list);
    OtherListViewAdapter other_adapter = new OtherListViewAdapter(this,
                                         R.layout.other_list_row, otherRowItems);

    otherListView.setAdapter(other_adapter);
    otherListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

the ViewAdapter:

```
holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(otherRowItem.getAppIconUrl());
```

so I can't really display the image in the `onPostExecute` because it's being displayed in other classes.

The idea is pretty simple, I have a loop where I'm getting a ParseFile and then AsyncTask gets the contents of the ParseFile and creates a Drawable from it. I tested the method without the AsyncTask and it works (but takes a long, long time).

I'm getting two errors:

1.) With `appIconDrawable[i] = DownloadImageTask.execute(pf);`, I'm getting: **Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask to Drawable**.

2.) With `fetchDrawable(pf);`, I'm getting **The method fetchDrawable(ParseFile) in the type ParseContent.DownloadImageTask is not applicable for the arguments (ParseFile[])**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Post execute will receive the drawable you create in the background if you want to do anything on the UI thread with the Drawable, this is where to do it.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Drawable dr) { ... }
```

The following line

```
appIconDrawable[i] = DownloadImageTask.execute(pf);
```

causes an error because execute does not return the drawable from doInBackground as you are expecting - that drawable is pased into onPostExecute instead (always).

Your second issue is a simple one - you are passing in a whole array of items when you only want one item. If you actually only have one item then its just a case of passing in that element -

```
fetchDrawable(pf[0]);
```

Otherwise if you want the whole array processed, loop through and kick of multiple tasks.

My suggestion would be to pass in a callback when you create the AsyncTask which you can save as a member variable and which will call a method in the calling class from onPostExecute.

```
public interface OnDownloadCompleteListener  {
    void onDownloadComplete(Drawbale dr);
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnDownloadCompleteListener {

   ...

   private void startDownloads() {
       new DownloadImageTask(this).execute();
   }     

   public onDownloadComplete(Drawable dr) {
       //when we get here the drawable is loaded, so use it however we want
   } 

}


public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<ParseFile, Void, Drawable> {

    private OnDownloadCompleteListener mListener;

    DownloadImageTask(OnDownloadCompleteListener odcl) {
          mListener = odcl;
    }

    ...

    public void onPostExecute(Drawable dr) {
       mListener.onDownloadComplete(dr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand. Could you post a snippet to lead me to the right direction? Thanks!